# Whats my vocal type?

Tags: voice, vocal-range

Hi guys my vocal range is G3-C5 what vocal type am I? I have just started singing last year in HS and really like it, however I would like to know what is my vocal type based off of my range. I used this video:

to test it

Answer (score 4):

Your vocal type is what your teacher/conductor determines it to be after testing you.  This is somewhat skewed through the lens of supply and demand: for example, I was pegged as a tenor even though the correct chest voice classification would have been bass baritone and I ultimately ended up singing alto to get rid of the vocal break in the middle of my most prominent range.

But it is useless for you to name a pitch range and expect a classification since nobody can guess what tone quality and control you have in the various parts of the total claimed range, what prominence your break has, how skilled you are navigating it.

You don't ask on the sports list whether you should rather train for the 500m or the 1000m distance specifying the diameter of your thighs when you haven't been to the track yet.

First you train the voice, *then* you determine your specialization.  Naturally when joining a choir, a (possibly temporary) voice group will have to be chosen based on your current condition.  The conductor is much more qualified to make this decision than anybody on the Internet.

Answer (score 1):

Male singers are not generally classified by the extremes of the vocal register; rather, they are classified specifically in terms of the timbre of the voice in connection to the strongest note sets (generally, these are diagnosed using basic five-note major scale patterns).

To summarize the findings of Richard Miller, however, the general determination of vocal tessitura for males is based on the first and second passaggi. This would be determined using both five-note scales and basic measure of both the falsetto register and a determination of the points of the voce mista (or voix mixte, if you prefer the French).

In any case, you cannot really make the determination on your own. One tool you CAN use is, to sing a rising chromatic scale until your voice is forced to change to falsetto (this is usually at the second passaggio for younger singers), then to reverse course, starting higher, and singing in falsetto down until your voice is forced to change to "chest" (normally the first passaggio, with some caveats).

One can then generally make a determination between those two pitches as to the general and specific tessitura of the voice.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

If by C5 you mean the C commonly known as Middle C (which is the most common definition of Middle C) then you are most likely a bass.  (Although basses are often asked to go to F3)  However a choir director who has three male sections might ask you to be in the Baritone section, if he or she has one.

If you're using a different definition for C5, then my answer is invalid.

Hope this helps.